# How does one use keras add_weight() vars with tensorflow probability distributions?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am creating a new keras layer which accepts a vector of input data and is parameterized by 2 scalars, a mean and standard deviation.  I model the input data as a normal distribution and estimate its mean and variance through gradient descent.  However, when I initialize tfp.Normal(mu, sigma) which mu and sigma are from add_weights() during, build(), the gradients do not propagate through mu and sigma.

The tensorflow probability documentation states that you can pass in training variables for distribution parameters and backprop through them.  How do I get this to work inside of keras?

Below is a minimal working example.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import numpy as np
tfk = tf.keras
tfkl = tf.keras.layers
tfd = tfp.distributions
tfpl = tfp.layers
EPS = 1e-5

batch_size = 4
N = 100
x = np.random.randn(batch_size, N)

class NormalLikelihood(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NormalLikelihood, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.mu = self.add_weight("mean", shape=[1], initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=1), dtype=tf.float32)
        self.sigma = self.add_weight("std", shape=[1], initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=EPS, maxval=5.0, seed=None), constraint=tf.keras.constraints.non_neg(), dtype=tf.float32)
        self.distribution = tfp.distributions.Normal(self.mu[0], self.sigma[0])

    def call(self, input):
        r = self.distribution.prob(input)
        r = tf.clip_by_value(r, 1e-3, 1-1e-3)
        return r

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(100,))
r = NormalLikelihood()(input_layer)
r = -tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.log(r))
model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_layer, r)
model.add_loss(r)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=None)
model.fit(x, y=None)
```

This code results in builtins.ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['normal_likelihood/mean:0', 'normal_likelihood/std:0'] which is not expected.  Desired behavior would be that ['normal_likelihood/mean:0', 'normal_likelihood/std:0'] have gradients provided for them.

See the code in google colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_u4XTCIH-2qwNSgv9zkZiCG_zeCIEZGp?usp=sharing

Comment: Please see how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @gobrewers14 Added a min working example.  Please upvote so this question can get traction.

Comment: change `tfp.distributions.Normal(self.mu[0], self.sigma[0])` to `tfp.distributions.Normal(self.mu, self.sigma)`

Comment: @gobrewers14 I see this works.  But, why doesnt my code work?  I don't see the difference.  Specifically, I am training a more complicated mixture of gaussian model.  If I have 5 gaussians in my mixture, I want to have 5 Normal distributions each with a different mu and sigma which is trainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `tfp.distributions.Normal(self.mu[0], self.sigma[0])` to `tfp.distributions.Normal(self.mu, self.sigma)`.

The reason this works is because under the hood of the `.fit()` keras method, the gradient computation is looking for trainable variables. When you index into the weights of the model you're taking the gradient against a constant that destroys the connectivity of the chain rule.

**Example**:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp


EPS = 1e-5


class NormalLikelihoodYours(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NormalLikelihoodYours, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.mu = self.add_weight(
            "mean", shape=[1],
            initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(
                mean=0.0, stddev=1), dtype=tf.float32)
        self.sigma = self.add_weight(
            "std", shape=[1],
            initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(
                minval=EPS, maxval=5.0, seed=None),
            constraint=tf.keras.constraints.non_neg(),
            dtype=tf.float32)
        self.distribution = tfp.distributions.Normal(self.mu[0], self.sigma[0])

    def call(self, input):
        r = self.distribution.prob(input)
        r = tf.clip_by_value(r, 1e-3, 1-1e-3)
        return r
    

class NormalLikelihoodMine(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NormalLikelihoodMine, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.mu = self.add_weight(
            "mean", shape=[1],
            initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(
                mean=0.0, stddev=1), dtype=tf.float32)
        self.sigma = self.add_weight(
            "std", shape=[1],
            initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(
                minval=EPS, maxval=5.0, seed=None),
            constraint=tf.keras.constraints.non_neg(),
            dtype=tf.float32)
        self.distribution = tfp.distributions.Normal(self.mu, self.sigma)

    def call(self, input):
        r = self.distribution.prob(input)
        r = tf.clip_by_value(r, 1e-3, 1-1e-3)
        return r

# loss function
def calc_loss(logits):
    return -tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.log(logits))

# model input
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(100,))
x_in = tf.random.normal([4, 100])

# your model
your_output = NormalLikelihoodYours()(input_layer)
your_model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_layer, your_output)\

# my model
my_output = NormalLikelihoodMine()(input_layer)
my_model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_layer, my_output)

# yours has no gradients because the network weights are not
# included anywhere in the loss calculation. When you index them
# with `[0]` they go from being trainable variables in the network,
# to just constants.
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_hat = your_model(x_in)
    loss = calc_loss(y_hat)
    
print(tape.gradient(loss, your_model.trainable_variables))
# [None, None]

# my model has gradients because `loss` and the weights in
# `trainable_variables` are connected
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_hat = my_model(x_in)
    loss = calc_loss(y_hat)
    
print(tape.gradient(loss, my_model.trainable_variables))
# [<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), numpy=array([43.83749], dtype=float32)>,
#  <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), numpy=array([-37.348656], dtype=float32)>]
```

Comment: So you are saying that indexing doesn't carry the gradients through?  What about for index slicing? I find it hard to believe that there is not a clean way to use indexing and preserve the gradients in tensorflow.

Comment: Compare the difference between `my_model.weights[0][0]` and `my_model.weights[0]`. The former is a `tf.Tensor` with a constant in it; the latter is a `tf.Variable` in your networks' graph with a specific namespace `'normal_likelihood_mine_3/mean:0'`.

Comment: I see your code but this doesn't quit make sense to me.  I have other code which uses index slicing and the gradients propagate fine.  I don't see why the single element case is special.  Would the syntax self.distribution = tfp.distributions.Normal(self.mu[0:1], self.sigma[0:1])  work?

Comment: I have updated the colab for a simple mixture of gaussians.  What is a good way to get this working? The code I posted gives me the same error wrt no gradients .

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229052/gradient-discussion